# MySQL left join custom query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**messages**:

```
id
thread_id
user_id
comment
timestamp
```

and **messages_status**:

```
id
message_id
user_id
status
```

The `user_id` from the messages table marks the ID of the user that created the comment, while the `user_id` from messages_status table marks the ID of a recipient user that sets the status (i.e. read/unread).

I use the following query to retrieve the messages from a thread:

```
SELECT `messages`.*, 
coalesce(messages_status.status, "unread") AS `status` 

FROM `messages` 

LEFT JOIN `messages_status` ON messages_status.message_id = messages.id 
and messages_status.user_id = 143

WHERE (thread_id = '40')
```

This way, when there is no row in the `messages_status` table for a certain message_id and user_id, it will return "unread".

However, if the value of `messages_status.user_id` from the query (e.g. 143) is the same with `messages.user_id` (i.e. the same user has created the comment), there is no row in the `messages_status` table, but the query should return "read" (if I am the user that created the comment, obviously I've also read it).

Is there a way to create such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding extra `IF` statement,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        IF(a.user_ID = 143, 'READ', COALESCE(b.status, 'unread')) AS `status` 
FROM    messages a
        LEFT JOIN messages_status b
            ON a.id = b.message_id
                AND b.user_id = 143
WHERE   a.thread_id = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger to be fired every time a new comment is made.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `AUTO_READ` AFTER INSERT ON `messages`
    INSERT INTO `messages_status`(message_id, user_id, status) VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.user_id, 'read');
END
```

That way, every time you insert a message, it will automatically create a row inside messages_status with the user ID to confirm that the one who made the comment, already saw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` for this something as

```
case 
 when messages_status.status is not null then "read"
 else "unread"
END as `status`
```